# MySQL do not allow Æ Ø Å on register

Tags: php, mysql

Now i got a register form that uploads a piece of info to my database table, but when i check for Æ Ø Å its messed up! this is my upload script:

```
<?php
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'errors');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    session_start();
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $about = $_POST['about'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO `usersystems` (`userid`, `fname`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `about`, `birth`) VALUES (NULL, '{$fname}', '{$username}', '{$password}', '{$email}', '{$about}', '{$date}');");
    header('Location: login.php');
?>
```

So now, how do i make it so the table actually allow those letters?

Comment: where else can i find a answer on this?

Comment: The linked duplicate should answer all your questions. Either your connection to MySQL is not UTF8, your database is not UTF8, the PHP is not saved as UTF8 or your HTML document doesn't use UTF8.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Database extensions cannot be freely mixed. If you use mysqli you have to stick to it, you cannot insert calls to the old legacy extension and expect it to work.

Comment: Problem solved!
i just put my database to swedish

Comment: Couldn't repair your Prius so got a Ford T? ;-P